# How to increase font size across entire MaterialApp?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `MaterialApp` in Flutter and want to scale up text throughout the entire app when a certain `fontFamily` is used in `ThemeData`.

Is this because this certain `fontFamily` looks smaller than other fonts.

Is there a way to scale up the font size of the entire app using `ThemeData`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ThemeData` you have `textTheme` property in which you can set the `TextTheme` for all widgets under that `MaterialApp`. In `TextTheme` you can set `TextStyle` for various types of texts in you app using parameters like caption, subhead etc. You can increase the size of the font by providing value for `fontSize` property in `TextStyle`

Something like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      caption: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22.0
      ),
      body1: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22.0
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```